# Beaker Notebook plotting in Scala

Tags: scala, beaker-notebook

I am looking to learn how to plot from Scala into a Beaker cell.

I've seen the plotting API which takes a JSON object and renders a plot, however I  cannot figure out how to leverage this functionality, or if there is a Java/Scala API injected into the Classpath I can leverage for this.

Does anyone have any help or pointers?

Answer (score 0):

There is, as you suggested, a Java API in the class path.  (You can see the automatic imports in the "Imports" section of the Scala or Java tab in the Language Manager.)  If you choose "Class Documentation" under "Help" you will see the documentation for these API classes.

Bad news: there is no real documentation to speak of.  There's method names and parameter types—basically what Javadoc will auto-generate for files that have no documentation.  The tutorials have some examples using Groovy, which may help some if you can do the mental conversion to Java/Scala.